# Cronjobs putting archive in wrong directory

Tags: debian, bash, cron, shell-scripting

I am running a website on an Amazon ec2 instance running the default Debian linux.  I set up a cronjob to copy the site files, take a database imprint, and zip them up.  I want to keep the file archives in the same directory as the bash script itself, which is located somewhat deep within /var/www/[a new directory]/[a new directory]/[etc]/.  I created a mysql user that can only read and dump the database, but cannot write to it.

The script is as follows

```
#/bin/bash

CURRPATH=$(pwd)
SITEPATH="/var/www/html"

MYSQLUSER="user"
MYSQLPASS="password"
MYSQLDB="database"

CURRDATE=$(date +"%Y-%m-%d__%T_%p")
DATETAG="Backup_$CURRDATE"
TEMPDIR="$CURRPATH/$DATETAG"
ARCHIVENAME="$DATETAG.zip"

# I first copy the files so I can stick a database imprint in the same directory
cp -r  "$SITEPATH/" "$CURRPATH/"
mv "$CURRPATH/html" "$TEMPDIR"
mysqldump -u "$MYSQLUSER" -p"$MYSQLPASS" "$MYSQLDB" > "$TEMPDIR/BackupDB_$CURRDATE.sql"

cd $CURRPATH
zip -r "$ARCHIVENAME" "$DATETAG"
rm -rf "$TEMPDIR"
```

I set this with crontab, and it works perfectly, except for one problem - the archive ends up in the ~/root folder (I set up the crontab with the root user).

Is there a way to get this archive to spit out in the same directory as the script, the $CURRPATH variable?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

CURRPATH is not the directory the script is in, it's the working directory that the script inherited from its parent process; for cron jobs, this is the home directory of the account it's running under (i.e. ~root). If you want the directory the script is in, use `CURRPATH=$(dirname "$BASH_SOURCE")` instead.

Comment: @NicholasFinch if this works, don't forget to accept the answer, and perhaps vote it up if you feel it warrants it.

Comment: I do not have enough of a reputation to vote it up - would otherwise do so gladly :)

Comment: Also - please excuse my obvious ignorance on this matter - what do I press to 'accept' the answer?

Comment: @NicholasFinch: You should see a check mark next to the answer. Click on it to mark the answer as accepted. Also, see [BashFAQ/028](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/028) regarding script locations.